# Poker tips backed by facts

Tags: poker-strategy, odds, statistics

I am looking for a list of quick poker facts similar to what WSOP (App) shows when a game is loading.

For e.g.

```
A player with a two pair at flops has a 16.7% chance of getting a full house.
```

I am looking for a comprehensive facts/tips cheat sheet.

Another example could be:

```
1) Ace high is the biggest straight possible.

2) There are no split pots in a flush hand unless it is a table flush.
```

Comment: "There are no split pots in a flush hand" What if the flush is made by the cards on the board

Comment: @David Great catch! I will edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These quick tips are all backed by the fundamental math and rules of poker. I would recommend that instead of memorizing facts/tips, it would be more beneficial to gain a thorough understanding of these rules and math.

Some things I would recommend learning and getting very fast at calculating are:

- counting outs
- calculating pot odds
- calculating equity vs. a hand
- the 2% 4% rule for counting outs as equity

if you insist on a list of poker facts, I found one that might be something that you are looking for but it purely contains odds and outs. https://www.cardplayer.com/poker-tools/odds-and-outs

Answer (score 1):

The list can be almost as big as you want, so I'd follow Clarko's advice. [Here](https://www.beatthefish.com/poker-strategy/texas-holdem-odds/) you have something that extends the "A player with a two pair at flops has a 16.7% chance of getting a full house." tip